# How to write to Elastic db in Dask?

Tags: python, sql, elasticsearch, dask, dask-distributed

How to write data after computation to Elastic DB in Dask ? 
like i need my output of my computation in a SQL DB and Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for "Dask Elasticsearch" on a search engine does bring up a few results.  I'm not personally familiar with them.

Alternatively, assuming that you're using dask dataframe you could use operations like map_partitions or to_delayed and then your own custom code.  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#learn-techniques-for-customization